# How can I limit ForEach to display a set of items in SwiftUI?

Tags: foreach, swiftui

I'm trying to write a query that would enable me to display only the first 5 items in an array using a ForEach loop.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
ForEach(fetcher.businesses) { item in

ExploreTile(image: item.image_url, name: item.name, category: item.categories[0].title)

}
```

Which returns hundreds of items. I saw someone reference using a range with ForEach

```
@State var range: Range<Int> = 0..<5
```

But I wasn't sure how to add that to the code within ForEach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understood you wanted

```
ForEach(fetcher.businesses.prefix(5)) { item in
```

Comment: thanks, .suffix gives you the last(n) guess that's why it's not .limit